# how to find string length using strlen in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode, string

i have a string strored in str variable i want to find string length which is available in str variable

i hav tried with strlen(str); its not working...

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If your string is a C-String, then you can use `strlen(str)`.

If it is a `NSString *str`, then you can use `NSUInteger length = [str length];`

Comment: But '[str length]' don't contain space's length.

Answer (score 10):

What type is your string?
If it's an NSString, you find the length like this:

```
int len = [myString length];
```

But it will be different if your string is not an NSString.

Answer (score 0):

Use length method, like this:

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello World";
int myLength = [myString length]; //myLength is now 11
```