# Print NSString length as an UIButton title

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I just took textField value into a string but I want to show the length of the string as a UIButton title.

Comment: then convert lenght in to string and set as button title. you also get direct textfiled.text length as well and for covert you can use [NSString stringWithFormate]

Comment: `[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.textfield.text.length] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

In textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: [buttonObj setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",strObj.length] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find string length using strlen in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846064/how-to-find-string-length-using-strlen-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set title of UIButton using following code:

```
[self.btnDemo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",self.txtDemo.text.length] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Where **btnDemo** is UIBUtton Outlet and **txtDemo** is UITextField Outlet

Here is code for change button title when user press button:

```
- (IBAction)checkLength:(id)sender {
    if (self.txtDemo.text.length == 0) {
        [self.btnDemo setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [self.btnDemo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",self.txtDemo.text.length] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

> Note: Put this code in UIButton **Touch Up Inside** event.

Answer (score -1):

use this line of code

```
   [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", string.length] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```